# p:ajax event="change" working in Tomcat 7 but not in Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf, primefaces, websphere

```
<html>

   <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="testID" disabled="false"
      value="#{listOfEmployeesBean.testName}"
      styleClass="mySelection"
      rendered="#{sacPeopleList.nameState eq 'testName123''}" >

   <p:ajax event="change" 
           listener="#{listOfEmployeesBean.onMyTestCheckBoxEventSelect}" />
   </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

</html>
```

The above code is working fine in Tomcat 7 but not in Websphere 8.5

Comment: some output error in the browser console?

Comment: Not single line of error

Comment: What JSF implementation is your project using?  What about CDI?

Comment: jsf (api and impl)-2.2.7